# Regex to get valid value

Tags: regex

I've been working on trying to check to see if there is a date, actually any value other than empty. I need it to stop after the date but if there is no value then there is no match. Basically, if there is either a value between `MRU_DATE_ACCEPTED::<VALUE>::` match if no value no match.

https://regex101.com/r/wpQlt9/1

Comment: This question is deadly unclear to me. Can you add sample data and your expected  match? Also what language are you using? For what I can understand, you want https://regex101.com/r/wpQlt9/3. But will be able to help if you provide more info.

Comment: A regex `MRU_DATE_ACCEPTED::<VALUE>`

Comment: 1. What part of the data do you need? 2. Is this `::` a delimiter ?

Comment: `::` is the delimiter it is `LABEL::VALUE::LABEL::VALUE`

Comment: What are you doing this in that you can't just use a tokenizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.*MRU_DATE_ACCEPTED::([^:]+?)::
```

It'll get the `<value>` if present (in the format `MRU_DATE_ACCEPTED::<VALUE>::`)

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wpQlt9/6)

Comment: Yes, but if there is no value just `MRU_DATE_ACCEPTED::::DISPOSITION` it will return `::DISPOSITION`